# Spring Boot 2.0 web flux custom authentication -- how to?

Tags: spring, security, reactive, spring-webflux

There are plenty of examples of minimal configurations of Spring Boot 2.0 security which compile or don't depending on which milestone or release candidate you try.

What is a minimal configuration that is *not* HTTP Basic, that will (1) let me access the HTTP request (headers, cookies, etc.) and also call my own authentication manager?

I would like to look at the headers and cookies, and decide from those who the user is, and whether or not the user is authenticated. How I do that should not matter to this answer -- the question is, what is the minimal Spring security config in order to allow me to hook in to the security infrastructure, so that my authentication is there in the reactive endpoints?

EDIT:

This works with Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC2, so my question could be, is this a correct way to introduce custom authentication into Spring Security?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

        AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(authentication -> {
            authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
            return Mono.just(authentication);
        });

        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationConverter(serverWebExchange ->
                Mono.just(new AbstractAuthenticationToken(new ArrayList<>()) {
                    @Override
                    public Object getCredentials() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object getPrincipal() {
                        return "jim";
                    }
                }));

        return http.addFilterAt(authenticationFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.FORM_LOGIN)
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .build();
    }
}
```

You can imagine that in the converter, I am free to look into the request by way of serverWebExchange and inspect any headers or cookies I wish, and that later in the upper lambda (standing in for ReactiveAuthenticationManager) I can actually decide whether or not it should be authenticated.